# jar deployment on application server

Tags: java, deployment, java-ee-6, jboss7.x

I have a executable jar and want to deploy it to an application server (jBoss AS 7.X).
I cannot go for Enterprise application project structure directly as This application does not need any web container. Further more it also doesn't need any Interface and do internal communication through message broker.
 I have developed it as normal java application. For communication to other moules it uses AMQP server for instance RabbitMQ.

```
Benefits for deploying on server
  - Centralization of all modules
  - Deployment is easy
  - Scalable
```

Running it as standalone app needs all modules to be started and managed separately and not easy for business users.

Another catch is that it has some configuration file that is in file system and cannot place them within jar as they might need to updated at runtime.

I can also not have Enterprise application structure as all modules within EE containers as some application are not java based (having different platforms such as .NET) and have different architectures.
I am new to java platform so suggest me some way out. Also suggest any better architecture for this and if jBoss is not solution.

Comment: The only advantage of a server is providing the framework for doing server-related things. If you don't use that, why do you want a server? (and no, your benefits are not valid). And even if it could be done... do you want to deploy AND configure AND deploy a JBoss in any user install? That is not as easy as it sounds.

Comment: The second "deploy" should read "secure"

Comment: I think management can be done from admin console of jBoss at port 9990. I can build management interface and host it through web container if needed in future.

Comment: another option instead of jboss is "as service". but in this case I will to manage service from myself. correct me if i am wrong.